# const and overloading operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I have generic map object. 
I want to overload the operator[] so `map[key]` return the key's value. 
I made two versions of the subscript operator.

non-const:

```
ValueType& operator[](KeyType key){
```

const:

```
const ValueType& operator[]( KeyType&   key) const{
```

The non-const versions works fine but when I  create const Map I have problem.
I write in the main:

```
     const IntMap map5(17);
     map5[8];
```

and I get these errors:

```
ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const IntMap {aka const mtm::MtmMap<int, int>}' and 'int')  


invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

Comment: `operator[]( KeyType&   key)` why `&` here?

Answer (score 0):

The error message about ambiguity reflects your compiler considering both of your `operator[]()` as possible candidates to match `map5[8]`.   Both candidates are equally good (or bad, depending on how you look at it).

The non-`const` version is invalid because `map5` is `const`.

The `const` version requires initialising a non-`const` reference to `KeyType` with an rvalue (the literal `8`) which is invalid.   From the error messages, your `KeyType` is `int`.

Either remove the `&` from the `KeyType` argument of the `const` version, or make that argument `const`.